# How do I clear up Documentum rendition queue?

Tags: documentum, opentext, documentum-dql

We have around 300k items on dmi_queue_item

If I do right click and select "destroy queue item" I see the that row no longer appears if I query by r_object_id.

[image]

Would it mean that the file no longer will be processed by the CTS service ? Need to know if this would it be the way to clear up the queue for the rendition process (to convert to PDF) or what it would it be the best way to clear up the queue ?

Also for some items/rows I get this message when doing the right click "destroy" thing, what does it mean ? or how can I avoid it ? Not sure if maybe the item was processed and the row no longer exists or is something else.
[image]

Comment: btw, where do you "right click"? DA?

Comment: aa Sorry,fort to mention I'm using dqMan 6.0 tool, just added up screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dmi_queue_item` table is used as queue for all sorts of events at Content Server. 
Content Transformation Service is using it to read at least two types of events, afaik.

*According to Content Transformation Services, Administration Guide, ver. 7.1*, page 18 it reads `dm_register_asset`s and performs the configured content actions for this specific objects. 
I was using CTS for generating content renditions for some objects using `dm_transcode_content` event.

However, be carefull when cleaning up `dmi_queue_item` since there could be many different event types. It is up to system administrators to keep this queue clean by configuring system components to use events or not to stuff up events that are not supposed to be used.

As per cleaning the queue it is advised to use `destroy` API command, though you can even try to delete row using `DELETE` query. Of course try to do this in dev environment first.

Comment: I'm filtering them by `name='dm_autorender_win31' and event='rendition' and message='rendition_req_ps_pdf'`  not sure if the message is a custom one (I'm not familiar neither with Documentum or this particular implementation) by I think that would it be good enough

Comment: for some items I get a fetch error message when trying the "destroy" function, is there any way to get rid of them as well ?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to look at 2 queues:

dm_autorender_win31 and dm_mediaserver. In order to delete them you would run a query:

delete dmi_queue_item objects where name = 'dm_mediaserver' or name = 'dm_autorender_win31'

Comment: getting no permission error even if I am trying from admin account